# Nuget not found exception for newly introduce package in CRM online plugin after deployment

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I am trying to modify my plugin and adding new nuget references. It is build fine in my local but after deployment it is giving exception "File (Azure.Idenityy.dll) not found." How to ensure that while using plugin.registration tool, dll references are getting deployed?

Comment: `Azure.Identity.dll` should be available, but probably a different version. Do you have the full error message because sometimes it includes version numbers

Answer (score 0):

If you use external dll (like your nuget package) there are two ways to include them inside a Dynamics CRM / Dynamics 365 CE Plugin.

The first is using ILMerge, this approach can work or not depends on the dll you are trying to merge.

The second is Dependent Assemblies, is a preview feature (as today only available online), documentation is at this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform-release-plan/2022wave1/data-platform/dependent-assemblies-plug-ins